# User acess rights using MemberOfGroups in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex

I have custome item type "Appeasement" , which contains attribute "appeasementStatus" of enum type "AppeasementStatusType" .

For customersupportagentgroup we dont have write access to item type "Appeasement" but I want to provide write access to attribute "appeasementStatus". I create below impex but this is not working as excepted.
Is any think missing?

```
enter code here
$START_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;;
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;customersupportagentgroup;;;;;;;;
;;;;Appeasement;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;AppeasementStatusType;+;+;+;+;-
;;;;Appeasement.appeasementStatus;+;+;-;-;-
$END_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: I also tried to do this and, from what I remember, because the Type has no "write" access granted, the attributes can not be configured to be writeable. What I did in that case was giving write access to the Type and removing the write access to all the other attributes except the one I wanted to be writable

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is not possible this way. Check the following section from https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8b4aa00e866910148df2920f69d68b27.html

> **Attribute Permissions**
>
> Using attribute permissions allows you to
>   explicitly assign permission to selected attributes of a certain type.
>   Attribute-related permissions don't override type-related permissions.
>   For example, if the type permission for a type is set to deny:
>   <Change>, you cannot grant permission: <Change> to any of the
>   attributes of that type. You can, however, set the type permission for
>   that type to permission: <Change>, and then decide which of the
>   attribute-related permissions you want to set to permission: <Change>,
>   and which to deny: <Change>.

As a summary, the type-level permissions can not be overridden to make less strict at attribute-level.

The workaround is the other way round i.e.

1. Grant `<write>` access to `customersupportagentgroup` for the  itemtype, `Appeasement`.
2. Deny `<write>` access to `customersupportagentgroup` for all the attributes, except `appeasementStatus`.